# How do I automatically pay users using paypal in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant, marketplace

Hey all, I'm trying to write a marketplace style application. Maybe E-Bay style in which the app connects buyers / sellers and then takes some commission.

I cannot use Amazon FPS as I don't have a US credit card. So my best option is probably paypal. Unfortunately, most of the material out there is all about telling me how the app can sell stuff.

I've heard I can payout using Paypal's mass pay system? If so, does anybody have any suggestions as per integrating this with my rails app. e.g. can it be done with ActiveMerchant?

Comment: This article looked promising talking about Paypal Mass Pay API
http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/paypal-masspay-ruby-example/ ...haven't tried it!

Comment: did you find any solution ...?